# WordpressBundle and remember me

Tags: php, symfony

For our application we're using Symfony2 in combination with the [WordpressBundle](https://github.com/kayue/WordpressBundle). I'm trying to enable the Symfony2 remember_me functionality, but whatever I try, it results in the following error:

`RuntimeException: You must configure at least one remember-me aware listener (such as form-login) for each firewall that has remember-me enabled.`

The firewalls in the security.yml look as follows, but I still get the above error. I've posted sort-of [an issue](https://github.com/kayue/WordpressBundle/issues/19) which also contains related issues.

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    main:
        pattern:    ^/
        anonymous:  ~
        remember_me:
            key: "%secret%"
            lifetime: 604800
            always_remember_me: true 
        form_login:
            login_path:       /login
            check_path:       /login_check
            remember_me:      true
        logout:
            path:   /logout
            target: /
        wordpress_cookie: false
        wordpress_form_login:
            remember_me:      true
            remember_me_parameter: _remember_me
```

Comment: where do you get `wordpress_form_login` from? Is bundle mandatory or is your initiative?

Comment: I make use of the WordpressBundle in order to easily use the wp codex functions in my Twig templates. The problem is that the bundle adds extra features to the application, like this `wordpress_form_login` provider. So, how can I manage that I lose the bundle-specific provider? Removing those lines from the config results in an unusable bundle

Comment: So `wordpress_form_login` is a name provided and mandatory from bundle?

Comment: Correct. It seems like the bundle doesn't implement the `form_login` correctly, but I've got no idea on how to fix / debug this, since by default the `remember-me aware listener` is configured via an .yml file